# Regular functions on locally closed sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{C}^n$ be endowed with Zariski topology.

**Definition 1** Let $X \in \mathbb{C}^n$ closed. A function $f : X \to \mathbb{C}$ is regular on $X$ if there exists a polynomial $F \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, ... x_n]$ such that $f(x) = F(x), \forall x \in X$.

**Definition 2** Let $X \in \mathbb{C}^n$ locally closed. A function $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ is regular on $X$ if there exists an open covering $\left\{ U_i \right\}$ of $X$ and polynomials $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, ... , x_n]$ such that $\forall i, b_i$ is not identically zero on $U_i$ and $f|_{U_i} = \frac{a_i}{b_i}$.

Now, we can prove the following result:

If $Z \in \mathbb{C}^n$  is closed, let $h \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, ... , x_n]$ a polynomial not identically zero on $Z$ and $X =Z_h$ (i.e. the subset of elements $x$ of $Z$ such that $h(x) \neq 0$)  then every regular function $f$ on $X$ can be written as $\frac{a}{h^d}$, with $a \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, .. x_n]$ and $d$ a positive integer.

It is argued that this result proves that on a closed set Definition 1 coincides with Definition 2, but I can’t seem to understand why. Any hints?

Comment: Clearly a regular function in the first definition is regular in the second one too. On the other hand, if $f$ is a regular function on a Zariski-closed set $Z$, then $Z=Z_1$ so any regular function on $Z$ must be some $a/1^d=a$ where $a$ is a polynomial – therefore this function is regular.

Comment: Oh right, thank you. If you want, you can make this as a answer, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer.

Clearly a regular function in the first definition is regular in the second one too. On the other hand, if $f$ is a regular function on a Zariski-closed set $Z$, then $Z=Z_1$ so any regular function on $Z$ must be some $a/1^d=a$ where $a$ is a polynomial – therefore this function is regular in the sense of definition 1.